# Error when generating a JAR with Enterprise WSDL

Tags: soap-api, soap, wsdl, null-pointer, enterprise-wsdl

I have generate `Enterprise WSDL` file and downloaded to my local machine. Now I'm trying to generate the `jar` file with following command.

`java -classpath .\..\..\..\..\..\.m2\repository\com\force\api\force-wsc\50.0.0\force-wsc-50.0.0.jar;.\..\..\..\..\..\.m2\repository\org\antlr\ST4\4.3\ST4-4.3.jar;.\..\..\..\..\..\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.5.2\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar`

Following is the output from above command.

```
[WSC][wsdlc.main:72]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC][wsdlc.main:72]Generated 1270 java files.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:48)
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Generator.compileTypes(Generator.java:136)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:129)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:163)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:72)
```

I noticed that some people has got exactly the same error. But I was unable to find a solution from those forums.

This may be a simple issue, but couldn't figure out the error using my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `JAVA_HOME` was set to an `oracle` version. when I corrected it, the error disappeared and `jar` files were generated.